# ASP MVC CRUD Erorr Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hy, I try to create CRUD using MVC ASP.Net but I have a problem when I run my program, I think the prolem is coming  from my connections
This the my web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="EmployeeEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Employee.csdl|res://*/Models.Employee.ssdl|res://*/Models.Employee.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Employee.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

and my model EmployeeDB:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace CRUDAjax.Models
{
    public class EmployeeDB
    {
        //declare connection string
        //string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmployeeEntities"].ConnectionString;

        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmployeeEntities"].ConnectionString;

        //Return list of all Employees
        public List<Employee> ListAll()
        {
            List<Employee> lst = new List<Employee>();
           // SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(cs);
            using(SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SelectEmployee",con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
                while(rdr.Read())
                {
                    lst.Add(new Employee { 
                        EmployeeID=Convert.ToInt32(rdr["EmployeeId"]),
                        Name=rdr["Name"].ToString(),
                        Age = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Age"]),
                        State = rdr["State"].ToString(),
                        Country = rdr["Country"].ToString(),
                    });
                }
                return lst;
            }
        }

        //Method for Adding an Employee
        public int Add(Employee emp)
        {
            int i;
            SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(cs);
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            //using (SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("InsertUpdateEmployee", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id",emp.EmployeeID);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", emp.Name);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", emp.Age);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", emp.State);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", emp.Country);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "Insert");
                i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            return i;
        }

        //Method for Updating Employee record
        public int Update(Employee emp)
        {
            int i;
            SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(cs);
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("InsertUpdateEmployee", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", emp.EmployeeID);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", emp.Name);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", emp.Age);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", emp.State);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", emp.Country);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "Update");
                i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            return i;
        }

        //Method for Deleting an Employee
        public int Delete(int ID)
        {
            int i;
            SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(cs);
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("DeleteEmployee", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", ID);
                i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Message erorr

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
       at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString, SqlCredential credential)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
       at CRUDAjax.Models.EmployeeDB.ListAll() in C:\Users\Jujur\Documents\CRUDAjax\CRUDAjax\Models\EmployeeDB.cs:line 24
       at CRUDAjax.Controllers.HomeController.List() in C:\Users\Jujur\Documents\CRUDAjax\CRUDAjax\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 20
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
  InnerException:
```

[ScreenShoot Erorr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UZbi.png)

Comment: The name of that connection string would leave me to believe it's an Entity Framework connection string for a database-first data model, which you can't use directly with a regular ADO.NET connection.

Comment: @TiesonT. i dont know what you mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception occurs just of because your connection string, you are giving entity framework, might be possible you've already used entity framework in the same project that's why connection string of `Entity Framework` appears.

```
connectionString="metadata=res://
```

Also notice this part for confirmation that you've used `EF`

```
App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

You connection string which uses `ADO.NET` would be something like this:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=SampleDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\SampleDB.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

to go to your database in `SQL Server` or if its local DB, right click on it, go to properties, copy connection string and replace it with your connection string within `web.config`, clear the solution and build will work.

Comment: this a code in my propertis > connection string `Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Jujur\Documents\CRUDAjax\CRUDAjax\App_Data\Employee.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30`  and then i changes my web.config like that `<add name="EmployeeEntities" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Jujur\Documents\CRUDAjax\CRUDAjax\App_Data\Employee.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />` 
But not fixed

Answer (score 2):

You should try updating you Connection string.

First connect your Database in your project, as described in this

[image]

after adding database you can get connection string from properties of database.
you can add that connection string to your `webconfig`.

Comment: Always try to attach images this way, so it will be easy for people to see the image and read the description at the same time despite of opening new window for the image.

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid  thank you for your good atention, poblem is solved